# laravel error "strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am passing json to a laravel route as following and I am runnig this query sql view.

> {"columns":["fname","lname","mobile"], "offset":"1", "limit":"25",
>   "order":[["fname","asc"],["lname","asc"]],
>   "filter":[["gender","=","M"]]}

**And this is the function placed in controller which will going to call on route**

```
public function fetch_contacts(Request $request){
    if($request->header('content-type') == 'application/json' && !empty($request->header('Device')) && !empty($request->header('UID'))){
          $query = DB::connection('mysql_freesubs')->table("contact_view")
              ->select($request->columns);

              if(!empty($request->filter))
                $query = $query->where($request->filter);

              if(!empty($request->offset))
                $query = $query->offset($request->offset);

              if(!empty($request->limit))
                $query = $query->limit($request->limit);

              if(!empty($request->order))
                $query = $query->orderBy($request->order);

              $contacts = $query->get();
              return $contacts;
}
```

**where am I going wrong ?**

Comment: I think so this error is somewhere else. can you pls check the file name and line number

Comment: in which line the exception got thrown ?

Comment: the error is in grammer.php which is a part of framework.     "ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: which line of your code triggers it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing multidimensional array to `orderBy`, try this instead:

```
$query = $query->orderBy($request->order[0][0], $request->order[0][1]);
$query = $query->orderBy($request->order[1][0], $request->order[1][1]);
```

Comment: we can do like this. where([["fname","=","sam"],["gender","=","M"]]);

Comment: You're right. But you can't do that with `orderBy()`